# Query parameter and multipart in retrofit android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I have to upload a video to server ...
the uploading url is like this `https://www.example.com/upload?id=80`

I am using retrofit to do so like this

```kotlin
@Multipart
@POST("UploadVideo?")
fun imageVideo( @Part file: MultipartBody.Part, @Query("id")  id : String):  Call<String>
```

with this I am not able to upload ... It looks like @part and @query are not working together.

How I can pass the query parameter with a multipart body?

Comment: remove the `?` from the POST annotation

Comment: getting this {"Message":"Exception Error reading MIME multipart body part.","Status":"Error","Id":-1}

Comment: Seems like your server is expecting some MIME type that you didn't supply in the request